# Why is the metric used in physics a squared norm?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, distance

The length metrics used in physics are usually a *squared norm*, like the following:
$$ds^2 = g_{\mu \nu} \, dx^{\mu} \, dx^{\nu}. \tag{1}$$

What other kinds of continuous metrics could we define?  Why not the following multi-linear candidates?
\begin{align}
ds &= g_{\mu} \, dx^{\mu}, \tag{2} \\[1ex]
ds^3 &= g_{\mu \nu \lambda} \, dx^{\mu} \, dx^{\nu} \, dx^{\lambda}, \tag{3} \\[1ex]
\vdots \\[1ex]
ds^n &= g_{\mu_1 \mu_2 \mu_3 \dots \mu_n} \, dx^{\mu_1} \, dx^{\mu_2} \, dx^{\mu_3} \dots dx^{\mu_n}. \tag{4}
\end{align}
What are the basic rules that "forces" physics to use the "squared" metric (1)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the metric have to be bilinear?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/511363/)

Comment: @JohnRennie, you're right that my question is a duplicate.  However, I don't find the answers very illuminating or satisfying.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/295454/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/233539/2451

Comment: @Cham the next step is to place a bounty on the previous question stating what you are looking for in an answer. This will encourage new answers to the previous question.